# Compile Error of ODataGen files with iOS 4.3

Tags: odata

Any idea of how to fix the following issue:

Error when compiling files generated by ODataGen (OData Client for Objective-C library V1.2) with iOS 4.3:

ld: warning: ignoring file odatalib/lib/iPhoneDeviceLibs/iPhone_Device_4.1/debug/libMSODataLib.a, missing required architecture i386 in file

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_ObjectContext", referenced from:

```
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ScheduleStatusContext in ScheduleStatusContext.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ObjectContext", referenced from:

```
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_ScheduleStatusContext in ScheduleStatusContext.o
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You are probably linking to the iOS version of the library, while there should be one for the i386 version of the simulator. You should start trying that